# Simple T4 template doesn't work in Visual Studio 2010, but does in MonoDevelop?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, mono, t4

I'm having all sorts of hell getting Visual Studio 2010 to compile my T4 template. I am pretty sure this same template worked on 2008, but I can't confirm right now. I know for sure it works on MonoDevelop.

Anyway, here is the header of my template:

```
<#@ template language="C#v3.5" hostspecific="true" #>
<#@ output extension="cs" #>
<#@ assembly name=“System.Core” #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
```

Visual Studio 2010 complains abut the first line, the template directive:

> A directive was specified in the wrong format. The transformation will
>   not be run. Please specify the directive in the format <#@ name
>   [parameterName="parameterValue"]*  #>

Why is this not working as expected?

Answer (score 5):

My problem was that I copy and pasted the `assembly` directive and it used `“”` instead of `""`

Also, I figured out that the line number it gives as the error is basically pointless.